# clang-tidy check to remove unnecessary class name before member function

Tags: c++, static-analysis, clang-tidy

Is there a clang-tidy check for replacing  `A::bar();` with just `bar();` in the following example?

```
class A {
  void bar() {
  };
  void foo() {
    A::bar();
  };
};
```

Comment: Have you referred to the [list of available checks](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/list.html)? I kind of doubt that this specific check would exist. I can't say I've ever seen a class name redundantly specified without a good reason (like disambiguation)

Comment: Are you asking for a way to force the compiler (in your case CLang) to raise a warning if someone is using that code-style? (hence for your comrade to remove it before commit)

Comment: @Human-Compiler I couldn't find one in the list of clang-tidy check. I was thinking a lintiing tool like clang-tidy should be able to do is.